# A pack contains $n$ cards labelled $1,2,3,...,n$. What is the probability that the $k$th card shows a larger number than its $k$ predecessors?

Tags: probability

A pack contains $n$ cards labelled $1,2,3,...,n$ (one number on each card). The cards are dealt out in random order.

What is the probability that the $k$th card shows a larger number than its $k$ predecessors?

My logic is as follows:

Take a typical selection of $n=7$ cards

1 3 2 4 6 8 7

If we select $k=4$ then $$\frac{(k-1)!(n-k)!}{n!}$$

Should give us the probability that the $k$th card shows a larger number than its $k$ predecessors? I am new to probability and i suck. The answer should be $1/k$

Comment: You do not need for the first $k-1$ entries to be specifically the values $1,2,\dots,k-1$ in some order.  You could have had as the example with 7 cards and $k=4$ be in the order 4 5 6 7 1 2 3 and this still count as the fourth card being larger than all cards that precede it.

Comment: The probability you found was the probability that not only was the $k$'th card larger than all cards that precede it, but also that the first $k-1$ cards were the numbers $1,2,\dots,k-1$ in some order.  That is more restrictive than was necessary.  One option for how to fix this is to choose what the $k$ first numbers were first.  This introduces a factor of $\binom{n}{k}$ into the numerator which if you pay attention will cancel almost everything.  Figure out what else needs to be adjusted, and you will be left with the expected answer of $\frac{1}{k}$ after all is said and done.

Comment: "probability that the $k$th card shows a larger number than its $k$ predecessors?" It should be "the $k-1$ predecessors, no?

Comment: Of course, the easiest approach is to just say "*well... the first $k$ cards are whatever they happen to be.  The last card of those $k$ is equally likely to be any of those $k$ cards, the probability the last happens to have been the largest is then $\frac{1}{k}$*"

Comment: To emphasize... yes, we *could* if we really wanted to work with our sample space being all $n!$ orderings of the entire deck... but you will learn that shortcuts are plentiful and by being more observant you can get away with a more efficient choice of sample space which focuses in only on those details that matter most, here the sample space could have been chosen to discuss only what rank the $k$'th card was in relation to the prior $k-1$ cards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might look harder than it really is.

Consider the first $k$ cards dealt. They will show $k$ different numbers, one of them will be the biggest one. The event of interest ("the kth card shows a larger number than its $k-1$ predecessors") is equivalent to the event "the biggest is the last one". By the symmetry of the problem, any of the $k$ cards can be the biggest one with  equal probability. Then the probability is $1/k$.

A much more convoluted way, using total probability. Let $E$ be event of interest (for fixed $k$) , let $v$ be the value of the $k-$th card. Then

$$P(E) = \sum_v P(E|v) P(v) = \sum_{v=1}^n \frac{\binom{v-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}} \frac{1} {n}
=\frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}   \binom{n}{k} = \frac{1}{k}$$

where we've used the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity