# A pack contains $n$ cards labelled $1,2,3,...,n$. What is the probability that each of the first $k$ card shows a larger number than its predecessors.

Tags: probability

A pack contains $n$ cards labelled $1,2,3,...,n$ (one number on each card). The cards are dealt out in random order.

What is the probability that each of the first $k$ cards shows a larger number than its predecessors? And what is the probability that the $k$th card shows $n$, given than the $k$th card shows a larger number than its $k-1$ predecessors?

To answer these questions I am using an answer from a a previous post

[A pack contains $n$ cards labelled $1,2,3,...,n$. What is the probability that the $k$th card shows a larger number than its $k$ predecessors?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4541826/a-pack-contains-n-cards-labelled-1-2-3-n-what-is-the-probability-that-t)

Let $E$ be the event that each of the first $k$ cards shows a larger number than its predecessors If we define $B_k$ as the event that the $k$th card shows shows a larger number than its $k-1$ predecessors. Then $E = \cap_{l=1}^{k}$ and $$P(E) = P(B_1)P(B_2)...P(B_k) = \frac{1}{k!}.$$

I do not have much of an idea where to start with the second question. I would like some guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct about the first part. I would personally prefer to think about it as follows:

> The first $k$ cards can come in $k!$ different orders, and they are all equally likely.

As for part 2, that's equivalent to

> What's the probability that the highest card among the first $k$ is $n$?

which is easily translated to

> What's the probability that $n$ is among the first $k$ cards?

and we easily see that this is $\frac kn$.

For a more rigorous calculation, consider Bayes' rule. Let $N$ be "The $k$th card is $n$" and $H$ be "The $k$th card is higher than all its predecessors". We have
$$
P(N\mid H) =\frac{P(H\mid N)P(N)}{P(H)}\\
=\frac{1\cdot \frac1n}{\frac1k}=\frac kn
$$